# Hadoop - Implement customize writable class with 2D ArrayList and Hashtable

Tags: java, hadoop, arraylist, mapreduce, hashtable

I have implemented a plain Java class Logdata and I'm trying to convert it to Hadoop Writable class. I know how to implement a writable class which contains simple int and String. But when it comes to data structures like 2D ArrayList, Hashtable, I have no idea how to do it. Can any one help me?

```
public class Logdata {
    ArrayList <Hashtable<String, String>> pairlist;
    ArrayList <byte []> buffvalue;
    ArrayList <ArrayList <byte []>> metadata;
    ArrayList <ArrayList <double[]>> timelines;
    int first, last;
    double timestamp;
}
```

Also do I need to implement all member variables in `write(DataOutput out)` and `readFields(DataInput in)`?

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994438/how-to-customize-writable-class-in-hadoop